# How do I derive the formula for the reciprocal of a hypotenuse?

Tags: geometry

Given $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$,

Why is it that the equation below yields the reciprocal of the hypotenuse c, ($\frac{1}c$)?

$\sqrt{(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2})^2 + (\frac{b}{a^2+b^2})^2}$

Worked example: 

 $3^2 + 4^2 = c^2$

 $c = 5$

 $\sqrt{(\frac{3}{3^2+4^2})^2 + (\frac{4}{3^2+4^2})^2}$

 = $\sqrt{(\frac{3}{25})^2 + (\frac{4}{25})^2}$

= $\sqrt{(.0144) + (.0256)}$

 = $\sqrt{.04}$

 = .2 or $1/5$

Comment: Your algebra needs practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that, for $ab\ne0$,
$$
\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2=\frac{a^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2}+\frac{b^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2}=\frac{a^2+b^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2}=\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}.
$$ Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2}&=\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{c^2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{c^2}\right)^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{c^4}+\frac{b^2}{c^4}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{c^4}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{c}
\end{align}
$$